# How do I get the program to perform the segue after loading user info?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a login screen with the username and password. I can currently load the username and password after the app is closed and opened back again, but I have to click the login button, instead I want it to perform the segue if the credentials are correct. I am using NSUserDefault to remember the credentials. Below is my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let usernameIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("username") as? String {
        self.usernameField.text = defaults.objectForKey("username") as? String
    }

    if let passwordIsNotNill = defaults.objectForKey("password") as? String {
        self.passwordField.text = defaults.objectForKey("password") as? String
    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
 @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = self.usernameField.text
    let password = self.passwordField.text


    if(username!.utf16.count) < 4 || (password!.utf16.count < 5){

    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Username must be greater then 4 and Password must be greater then 5", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()

    }else{

        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username!, password: password!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((user) != nil) {

                //var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                //alert.show()
                var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                defaults.setObject(self.usernameField.text, forKey: "username")
                defaults.setObject(self.passwordField.text, forKey: "password")
                defaults.synchronize()


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)


                })

            }else {

                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            }



        })

    }


}
```

Comment: ok whats the issue you faced my bro

Comment: So when I open the app, the username and the password fields are filled with the correct credentials, but I have to click the login button instead I want the segue to perform instead of me clicking the login button.

Comment: Describe what's not working as expected so we can get a better sense of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should ***not be storing a user's password in standard user defaults as plain text.*** If you're not writing an application that requires web access, then there's no point in making them log in really, and thus you wouldn't need to implement this. If a user needs an account for your app, I would suggest implementing one through a backend such as Parse which will happily handle the password more securely than you will.

Comment: I am using parse, any suggestions for auto login with parse backend?

Comment: Well if you are using parse there's absolutely no reason you should be storing this info at all in `NSUserDefaults`. What you instead need to check for is `if PFUser.currentUser()! != nil { self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", animated: true) }`

Comment: This didn't answer OP's question about performing a segue after a check for credentials.

Comment: Actually it specifically answer his question (in the comment right above yours) and further clarified to a clear beginner something they may not have known and probably taught them something about proper ways to handle user data.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidAppear() {}
```

This function will excecute when the view is on the screen. So in this method go check for the credentials in NSUserDefaults. If theres some info in there excecute this

```
self.actInd.startAnimating()

    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username!, password: password!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

        self.actInd.stopAnimating()

        if ((user) != nil) {

            //var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            //alert.show()




            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)


            })

        }else {

            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

        }



    })
```

But the username and password variables should be the ones from NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt, check that user id and password are stored.

If they stored in device, check and push next viewcontroller.

For example,

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
if let userDefaults.objectForKey("username"){
    if let userDefaults.objectForKey("password"){
        // do login process
        // if user id and password are valid then
        let nextViewController = YourViewController();
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}
// else alert some message and stay in loginViewController
```